# Использование двух камер в Unity одновременно

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на  кнопку изображение частично переключалось на другую камеру, накладывалась на главную, частично её перекрывая, с возможностью взаимодействия с тем что видит эта другая камера.

Наиболее понятно будет если я скажу что мне нужно вызывать окно "инвентарь" в игре - Вылезает сбоку окошко, там вещи, их можно перетаскивать, по нажатию клавиши окошко появляется или убирается. Может это и не с камерой оптимально делать.

Comment: Непонятно как раз таки. Вторая камера нужна, например, когда хочется сделать minimap как в CS. А для окна инвентаря достаточно использоваться UI.  Так что, в принципе, непонятно, что и как должно быть.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ну значит камера не нужна. Нужно открывающееся окно, как инвентарь, не на весь экран, как например в Diablo. В инвентаре мне нужно взаимодействовать с мини 2d игрой, двигать блоки. Отдельно она уже есть. Нужно только чтобы при нажатии кнопки вылезала, поиграл, закрыл.

Comment: Актуально или нет но, я инвентарь делал по через UI вот по этому уроку всё доходчиво хоть и на английском: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxRAIjXdfFU

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/221315)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно создать окошко интерфейса то смотрите в сторону [UI](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui). Уроки на английском, но по видео вроде бы все понятно, в крайнем случае включите титры на русском.

Если же нужно выводить изображение поверх другого изображения(например рисовать живую карту), то достаточно добавить в систему [камеру](http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-Camera.html), настроить в камерах `Culling Mask`(слои которые должны отрисовываться в камеру) и `Depth` (глубина или иначе слой) для очередности отрисовки, да и не забудьте в камере которая сверху поставить `Clear Flag` = `Depth Only`. После этого можно делать с камерой что угодно, двигать, крутить, вращать, отключать и включать по мере необходимости.

Comment: Важный вопрос - при использовании второй камеры, я могу взаимодействовать со всем что она показывает или она только показывает? 

Про UI вы имеете ввиду UI-slider?  Хорошо, а как в нем вывести, например, match3 игру, если изначально она отрисовывалась не на UI а просто через Instantiate, расставляя по координатам? Ведь у UI какая то своя система отсчёта?

Comment: Сама камера работает точно также как и вторая камера, она занимается только рендерингом со сцены. Поэтому вы можете управлять объектами как и при работе с основной камерой. Главное раскидать объекты по нужным слоям, и определить в камерах какие слои отрисовывать. Почитайте справку, там на русском подробно все написано.

Comment: По UI если вы хотите сделать окно с инвентарем посмотрите туториалы, в двух предложениях все не расскажешь. Обычно интерфейс рисуется отдельно от самой игры. Там предусмотрено три режима, разбирайтесь какой вам подойдет. Вот урок,(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xe22tGE66qU).

Answer (score 2):

Для создания инвентаря, настоятельно рекомендую использовать `UI` элементы, а не вторую камеру.

**Причины:**

- Вторая камера - в два раза больше отрисовки. И та камера отрисовывает кадры и эта.
- Вам необходимо создать интерфейс инвентаря, как я понимаю, а для интерфейса используют `UI` элементы (UI - User Interface).
- `UI` предоставит вам удобство в работе. Не нужно писать свои скрипты для кнопок и так далее.

Материал для изучению UI элементов: http://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui
материал на английском языке, но я так думаю, что всё будет понятно.